# ASP.net version in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I heard that Sharepoint use asp.net but which asp.net? Is it classical or MVC version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what classical means exactly but it definitely is not MVC.

[From the whitepaper: The SharePoint 2010 Developer Platform](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=7563&6B49FDFB-8E5B-4B07-BC31-15695C5A2143=1)

The 2010 release of SharePoint can be viewed in three parts:

1. Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010: The basis of everything else in 
   SharePoint, SharePoint Foundation 2010 is the successor to Windows 
   SharePoint Services 3.0.
2. Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010: The successor to Microsoft Office SharePoint 
   Server (MOSS) 2007, this product contains a group of technologies that address 
   more specialized problems. While SharePoint Server 2010 is built largely on 
   SharePoint Foundation 2010, it’s a separate product—using it requires 
   purchasing a license.
3. SharePoint Online: A Microsoft-hosted version of SharePoint technology, this 
   offering lets both users and developers use SharePoint’s functionality without 
   installing any on-premises SharePoint software.

On the used technology for SP2010 (from the [Glidepath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee537834%28v=office.14%29.aspx)):

> SharePoint Foundation 2010 uses Microsoft ASP.NET 3.5, even if a later version of ASP.NET is also installed on the front-end Web server.

As for the [former MOSS2007 version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc537498%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

> ...with the release of the 2007 Microsoft Office system, Microsoft provides products and technologies such as Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 and Microsoft Office SharePoint Server 2007 that are built on top of ASP.NET 2.0.

Answer (score 5):

MOSS 2007 - ASP.NET 2.0
SharePoint 2010 - ASP.NET 3.5